# XSL XML to HTML

Tags: html, xml, xslt, transformation

I have assignment for school , but i cant find a way to make it how it supposed to be so i will appreciate if someone help me .
This is my xml code

```
<cinemaSchedule>
<Date13.11.2014>

    <movies >
        <title>Dracula Untold </title>
        <gener>Horror</gener>
        <raiting>C</raiting>
        <language>EN</language>
        <runtime>92</runtime>
        <projection>17:50  19:45  21:50</projection>
    </movies>
    <movies id="wtf2">
        <title>The November Man </title>
        <gener>  Action </gener>
        <raiting>C</raiting>
        <language>EN</language>
        <runtime>108</runtime>
        <projection>22:00</projection>
    </movies>
</Date13.11.2014>

<Date14.11.2014>

    <movies id="wtf9">
        <title>Dracula Untold </title>
        <gener>Horror</gener>
        <raiting>C</raiting>
        <language>EN</language>
        <runtime>92</runtime>
        <projection> 13:50  15:45   17:40   19:40    22:20</projection>
    </movies>

    <movies id="wtf11">
        <title>Jessabelle</title>
        <gener>Horror</gener>
        <raiting>C</raiting>
        <language>EN</language>
        <runtime>90</runtime>
        <projection> 14:20      16:20       18:20     20:20 </projection>
    </movies>
</Date14.11.2014>
</cinemaSchedule>
```

And this is my xsl code .. but it doesn't work right .. the every  date should be tittle of a table ..

```
<xsl:template name="table" >
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Gener</th>
        <th>Raiting</th>
        <th>Language</th>
        <th>Runtime</th>
        <th>Projection Hours</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="cinemaSchedule//*">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="title" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="gener" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="raiting" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="language" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="runtime" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="projection" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
</table>
</xsl:template>
```

And everything should look like this.. exalpe: http://puu.sh/g08qy/f70e81bc2c.png but for cinema

Answer (score 0):

I think i found a solution to your problem. Though it would have been easier if the date was part of data and not as an independent node.

Part 1# here i have taken child nodes under  node and passed them to the template **"subnodes"**. Params will have the *datenode*s.

```
    <xsl:template match="/" >
<table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="10" border="5">
<tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Gener</th>
        <th>Raiting</th>
        <th>Language</th>
        <th>Runtime</th>
        <th>Projection Hours</th>
    </tr>

    <xsl:for-each select="cinemaSchedule/*">
<tr> 
<xsl:call-template name="subnodes">
  <xsl:with-param name="currentNode" select="."/>
</xsl:call-template>
</tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
</table>
</xsl:template>
```

Part 2# In the "subnode" template i have looped through the *datenodes* and used the name() function to get the name of the *datenodes*.

```
<xsl:template name="subnodes">
<xsl:param name="currentNode"/>
<xsl:for-each select="$currentNode/*">
<tr>
<td>
<xsl:value-of select="name($currentNode)"/>
</td>
<td>
<xsl:value-of select="title"/>
</td>
<td>
<xsl:value-of select="gener"/>
</td>
<td>
<xsl:value-of select="raiting"/>
</td>
<td>
<xsl:value-of select="language"/>
</td>
<td>
<xsl:value-of select="runtime"/>
</td>
<td>
<xsl:value-of select="projection"/>
</td>
</tr>
</xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

FULL XSL CODE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/" >
<table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="10" border="5">
<tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Gener</th>
        <th>Raiting</th>
        <th>Language</th>
        <th>Runtime</th>
        <th>Projection Hours</th>
    </tr>

    <xsl:for-each select="cinemaSchedule/*">

<tr> 
<xsl:call-template name="subnodes">
  <xsl:with-param name="currentNode" select="."/>
</xsl:call-template>
</tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
</table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="subnodes">
<xsl:param name="currentNode"/>
<xsl:for-each select="$currentNode/*">
<tr>
<td>
<xsl:value-of select="name($currentNode)"/>
</td>
<td>
<xsl:value-of select="title"/>
</td>
<td>
<xsl:value-of select="gener"/>
</td>
<td>
<xsl:value-of select="raiting"/>
</td>
<td>
<xsl:value-of select="language"/>
</td>
<td>
<xsl:value-of select="runtime"/>
</td>
<td>
<xsl:value-of select="projection"/>
</td>
</tr>
</xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[xslt](/questions/tagged/xslt) [xml](/questions/tagged/xml)